# Feedback on my part-whole analysis, regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I have about 200 test items that contribute to 8 sections of a test, called Brain_Test. The 8 sections are converted to standardised scores. The standardised scores are individually interpreted, or added to provide an overall test score and interpretation.

I am interested in a small part of a section. Let's call it Section A, Part 2.5. I have conceptualised this part differently, used its scores to view the data in different ways, through creating new variables, for example reverse scoring them. E.g. where a case can score 5 x1 point items, I have given a different weighting to the items of 1,2,3,4,5, a total of 15, and not 5.

I am interested in whether these new variables can be used to help predict a proportion of the overall test score. I believe this small part taps a common skill which underlies the overall Brain_Test score and could be useful clinically.

However, it would appear I am guilty of the part-whole problem AKA circularity. I have mulled over the problem and sought help but remain befuddled. I have chosen not to split the data into two separate groups, and do not want to go down a complex analysis route.

To avoid the apparent circularity I removed Section A completely from the overall Brain_Test score (No_A_Brain_Test), and then computed a [stepwise] regression using my new variables. They are significant at a <.001 level and each have an adj R2 value of between .18 (singlularly) and .41 (combined).

Of course I can no longer convert Section A to a scaled score, nor is the overall Brain_Test score interpretable as a standardised score, there is no way to compute it as a whole when you just have the predictor values. However, in using the predictors in the model, I can plug in a case's scores and get an estimate of their overall Brain_Test score.

I now intend converting the new No_A_Brain_Test score into z-scores, which will provide standardised values for this sample. I would need to also provide ranges via confidence intervals. Does anyone know how to do that on SPSS? I guess I would need to calculate upper and lower limits.

Really interested to know if anyone sees fault with my statistical methodology? Maybe I have gone very wrong somewhere. Appreciate any help.